# Codecademy - my code returns true, but it says I missed something else?

Tags: javascript

The code shown below works and it returns true. But I'm being told that there is another problem which I'm not catching. Perhaps a fresh pair of eyes will see what I don't. The error says:

> Oops, try again. Make sure your if/else statement evaluates to true!

**Code**:

Here is the starting code they provided:

```js
 ("Jon".length * 2 / (2+1) === )
{
    console.log("The answer makes sense!");
}

else
```

Here is my answer with some things filled in:

```js
if ("Jon".length * 2 / (2+1) === 2) {
    console.log("True");
} else {
    console.log("Error Error Error");
}
```

**Assignment**:

> Math
>
> We saw basic math before. The basic math symbols we learned in school work here. Even the order in which the computer understands the math is the same as in school!
>
> Code:
>
> 1. ( ): control order of operations
> 2. * and /: multiplication and division
> 3. - and +: subtraction and addition
>
> Examples:
>
> 1. 100/10 evaluates to 10
> 2. "Jane".length + 5 evaluates to 9
> 3. 5*(3+1) evaluates to 20
>
> Instructions
>
> Complete the missing bits of code to construct the if / else statement. Make the condition evaluate to true.
>
> Finish the else statement by printing out the string "Error Error Error" to the console.

Comment: If you don't tell what the function is supposed to do then it's pretty much impossible to say what the problem is.

Comment: @Juhana the instructions simply says: Complete the missing bits of code to construct the if / else statement. Make the condition evaluate to true. Then, Finish the else statement by printing out the string "Error Error Error" to the console.

Comment: There's not even a function here.

Comment: You'll have to show the entire text of the assignment.

Comment: ok @Juhana i just did......

Comment: Thats what i was saying @Mathletics, but it doesn't let me move on till i figure out what exactly they want me to do. The only thing i have done was add an extra "=" to make it "===" and put "" inside the console.log line.

Comment: Why would you make either of those changes?

Comment: @Mathletics because originally the code was written like this: (if ("Jon".length * 2 / 2+1  == 2){ console.log(True); }else{ console.log("Error Error Error")

Comment: You have `(2+1)` in the post but `2+1` in your comment; which one are you submitting? It seems like the question wants you to fix the order of operations.

Comment: @DanLowe I notice. I been on the forum and still waiting for an responds and/or clarity on the question.

Comment: @Mathletics sorry about that. I edit and post the original and my answer on the post.

Comment: wow! smh... good call @DanLowe. I didn't think that would've been the issue but it was.

Comment: @Checkk Deleted my comments and reformulated as an answer so it would be more readily usable to future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codecademy uses a number of methods to determine whether or not you have passed the lesson. They seem to check the ending value of various objects in the code (the value of variables, return value of functions...), but they also parse the code you submitted using regular expressions or similar, looking for certain things. Unfortunately, determining what those things might be is sometimes more of a puzzle than the code they wanted you to write in the first place.

Now that you have updated your question with the assignment text and the starting code you were given, as well as your submitted code, the most likely issue would seem to be that you modified the text in the true-case `console.log` statement.

```js
// Their version
console.log("The answer makes sense!");

// Your version
console.log("True");
```

They are probably checking that the expected string was logged to the console. Since you changed what was logged, this test would be failing.

Often on Codecademy, "do exactly what the instructions say" counts as much, or even more, than writing code that works.

Answer (score 1):

Codecademy is very strict in uses of there lessons. The functionality of the problem above was correct, however the site doesn't like it when you customize there code like I did. When modified the text in the console.log statement, it prevented from moving forward with the lesson.

```
// Their version
console.log("The answer makes sense!");


// Your version
console.log("True");
```

I learned that often on Codecademy, you have to do exactly what the instructions say, or even more, than writing code that works.